# Input File multiple Validation Javacript

Tags: javascript, validation, input

It is possible to validate within a multiple Input file that one of the files is of type word (.doc, .docx) and another of type PDF (.pdf)?

Comment: you can use the `accepts` attribute

Comment: Do you care about the file _extension_? Or what the file actually _is_? For example, I can take a `.exe` file, and give it a `.pdf` extension, despite it still being a binary executable. So you probobly want the file _dialog_ to be extension-based as that is what it supports. But if you're going to use the file, you probobly want to look at what the file is as opposed to whatever extension the user gave it to avoid unfortunate vulnerabilities in your code. Also, if the server will use it, validate the actual file type server-side as the client can NOT be trusted.

Comment: If you are only using Chrome, here is another way to do it: https://web.dev/file-system-access/

Comment: What I mean is that I need to validate in a process, that within the input file there are at least 2 files, one Word type and the other PDF type, I could accept up to 6 files, JPG, escel etc... But what what really matters to me is to validate that within that group of files there are 2. one of type WORD and another of type PDF

Comment: @DanielLazarte You mean the client is selecting a .tar or.zip file that contains multiple files? If not tar or zip, what protocol are you using for blobbing files together?

Comment: No, not ZIP, Up to 6 files are allowed in an input file, of type JPG, EXCEL WORD and PDF. But minimally the Word file and the PDF file must exist for the process to continue. Consider that in the case of Word it can be DOC or DOCX

Answer (score 0):

I have a created a [working codepen](https://codepen.io/lucasroquilly/pen/eYVKWYM) that shows you a javascript code which iterates over the files uploaded with the file upload input, and checks if their file extension is in pdf, doc or docx.

Though as others have mentioned in comments, checking file format in client-side is unsafe and you should double check on the server side.

Snippet below

```js
function testFiles(){
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('upload');   
        // iterate over files
        for (let i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
            var filename = fileInput.files[i].name
            // get file extension
            var file_extension = filename.split('.').pop()
            if(file_extension == "pdf" 
               || file_extension == "doc"
               || file_extension == "docx"){
              alert(filename + ' is a .pdf, .doc or .docx file')
            }                 
            else alert(filename + ' is not an authorized file')
        }
}
```

```html
 <input id="upload" type="file" onchange="testFiles()" multiple>
```